# How to include Custom Js in Bootstrap's custom Sub Theme directory For Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drupal

My custom theme doesn't read the JavaScript file that I have linked in `.info` file. All the paths to directory are correct. While inspecting the page it shows only the default bootstrap script files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. My workaround was to include the script in my html.tpl.php file:

1. Find html.tpl.php under sites > all > themes > bootstrap > theme > system.
2. Make a copy of the file and add it do your custom theme directory (sites > all > themes > your custom theme).
3. Create a folder in your custom theme for all your javascript and name it js.
4. Add your javascript file to the js folder.
5. Open the html.tpl.php file you copied to your custom theme, and insert the following line anywhere between the  tags:
6. Save, then flush your chache and you should be good to go.